# Calculating conditional expectation, confused on integration bounds?

Tags: probability

I am given a joint density, $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=a^2e^{-ay}$$I need to calculate both $E[X\mid Y=y]$ and $\operatorname{Var}[X\mid Y=y]$.

I am also given that $a>0$ and that $(0<x<y<\infty)$.

---

$$E[X\mid Y=y]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)\,dx$$

So I'll start by calculating marginal and conditional densities. But this is where I'm getting hung up on the bounds. I'll be integrating with respect to $y$ for this first integration, and I can't figure out what I should change the bounds to.

$$f_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dy$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}a^2e^{-ay}dy$$

Once I figure out what the bounds are, then I can calculate:

$$f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)=\frac{f(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$$

And then, finally:

$$E[X\mid Y=y]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)\,dx$$
$$\operatorname{Var}[X\mid Y=y]=E[X^2\mid Y=y]-(E[X\mid Y=y])^2$$

So I generally see what to do here, but I am missing the really basic concept of the bounds. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
f_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dy & =\overbrace{\int_x^\infty a^2e^{-ay} \, dy} \\[10pt]
& = \left.-ae^{-ay}\vphantom{\frac11} \right|_{y\,:=\,x}^{y\,:=\,\infty} = ae^{-ax} & \text{for } x>0.
\end{align}
You had
$$
f_X(x)= \overbrace{\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dy}^\text{right} =\overbrace{\int_{-\infty}^\infty a^2e^{-ay} \, dy}^\text{wrong}.
$$
You can use this to find the marginal expected value and the marginal variance of $X$.

Where you wrote "I am given$\,\ldots$", you didn't finish the sentence until later where you wrote "I am also given$\,\ldots$".

Comment: Was that edited out? I don't see the unfinished sentence. But thanks. Also, on the "wrong" part, is it wrong because of the bound?

Comment: @Taylor: It was wrong because of the lower bound.  Where you  wrote "I am also given", that is essential to what the density is.  That's what you didn't finish.  You haven't said what the density function is before you have the part that you were "also given". $\qquad$

Comment: I gave the joint density...? Are you asking me to clarify? I'm more confused about what you're saying here than the question

Comment: You gave the joint density in what was in effect a sentence that got interrupted and continued later. $\qquad$

Comment: Oh. Sorry, then.